# OVERLAPS for Informix

Tags: date-format, informix

Does Informix have a function equivalent to OVERLAPS, which finds out whether or not two time intervals have any time in common?

Comment: How are you storing these time intervals? In two columns, say `StartTime` and `EndTime`?

Comment: Exactly, two columns from two different tables with start and end dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a `OVERLAPS()` function that you could use. You'll have to stick to the usual test:

```
WHERE a.StartTime < b.EndTime
  AND b.StartTime < a.EndTime
```

Change `<` to `<=`, depending on how you want your Overlap test to function on end cases, when an end time (or date) is exactly the same as the other start time. I guess such behaviour may be wanted for dates.